# How to Prevent my Images from overflowing in CSS?

Tags: css

Here is the codepen showing what is happening https://codepen.io/designextras/pen/abdMwrP

I tried to add overflow: hidden and overflow-x, y but it still didn't work.

I'm using before and after cause I have two svgs that I need displayed on the right side

```
 .container {
max-width: 100%;

 }

 .container:before {
content: '';
display: block;
position: absolute;
background: url(images/svg-gradient.svg) no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
max-width: 855px;
top: 0%;
right: -5%;
 }

 .container:after {
content: '';
display: block;
position: absolute;
background: url(images/dashboard-svg.svg) no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
max-width: 855px;
top: 30%;
right: -10%;
transform: rotate(-20deg);
 }
```

[image]

Comment: I see 2 square boxes, would you mind explaining what is overflowing on what? and how the fix should look like?

Comment: if you see it has the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom and I need that to disappear, so the boxes basically get cut and don't overflow

Comment: yeah I need the overflow sections to be cut out

Comment: This may help you : http://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/xsoj65dm/199/

Answer (score 0):

You add this in css AND disable `x` srolling,

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden
}
```

Add this to `.container:before` and `.container:after`

```
z-index: -1;
```

And the complete working thing,

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  background: yellow;
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 855px;
  top: 0%;
  right: -5%;
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 855px;
  top: 30%;
  right: -10%;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.navbar-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80px;
}

#logo {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2C2C2C;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

#btn {
  background: #50CDFB;
  height: 146px;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
}

.new-section {
  background: red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <div class="navbar-menu">
        <a href="#" id="logo">Startup</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id='btn'>Signup</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div>New section</div>
  </div>
  <div>I need to be under everything</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Brian please mark as answer and upvote if it helped

Comment: so I added it and it got rid of the scroll, but do you know why the images are taking up so much space? cause if I add a new div to the code, it won't be at the bottom of the blue and red square. I colored the container to be yellow so you can see that it only shows like 80px height when I need that entire background with the images to be yellow

Comment: @Brian check out now

Comment: I added an image with the style I'm trying to replicate. So pretend the blue and red boxes are the hand with phone image and the yellow background div is the entire home section. Then the green background that I added, needs to below all of those divs so it would look like the white section below saying we create exclusive brands

Comment: actually I think I figured it out, but lmk if you had a better way to write it